# beautifulsoup - Fetching text either side of a br tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have unfortunately become stuck with the following problem:

```
 <a href="someurl"> 
"TEXT ONE"
 <br>
 "TEXT TWO"
 </a>
```

I need text one and text two separately.
I can only obtain them as a whole providing `"TEXT ONE TEXT TWO"` by using `"text = container.a.text"`, with the container being a parent of the a tags. I have tried as many ways as I could find with no success. I can't manage to use `br` tag properly. 
Thank you for any help.

Comment: What parser are you using here (`lxml`? `html.parser`?)

Comment: html.parser is what I've been using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.previousSibiling` and `.nextSibling` attributes after finding the `br` tag:

```
>>> container.a.find("br").previousSibling
' \n"TEXT ONE"\n '
>>> container.a.find("br").nextSibling
'\n "TEXT TWO"\n '
```

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid relying on the presence of the `br` element and would instead *locate all the text nodes inside the `a`*:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: html = """ <a href="someurl"> 
    ...: "TEXT ONE"
    ...:  <br>
    ...:  "TEXT TWO"
    ...:  </a>"""

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

In [4]: [item.strip() for item in soup.a(text=True)]
Out[4]: ['"TEXT ONE"', '"TEXT TWO"']
```

Note that `a(text=True)` is a short version of `a.find_all(text=True)`.

---

You can, of course, *unpack it into separate variables if needed*:

```
In [5]: text_one, text_two = [item.strip() for item in soup.a(text=True)]

In [6]: text_one
Out[6]: '"TEXT ONE"'

In [7]: text_two
Out[7]: '"TEXT TWO"'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will try this out too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in several ways. Here is another way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content='''
 <a href="someurl"> 
"TEXT ONE"
 <br>
 "TEXT TWO"
 </a>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
for items in soup.select('a'):
    elem = [' '.join(item.split()) for item in items.strings]
    print(elem)
```

Output:

```
['"TEXT ONE"', '"TEXT TWO"']
```