# Is there an easier way to webscrape br tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been searching for a way to correctly extract the address data.

This is my python script excerpt:

```
addr = soup.find('div', class_='col-md-4')<br/>
print(addr)<br/>
print(addr.text)
```

results:

```
<div class="col-md-4">45120 Waxpool Road<br/>20166 Dulles, VA<br/>USA</div>

45120 Waxpool Road20166 Dulles, VAUSA
```

Need to create/print results as follows to separate address, city, state, zip....:

45120 Waxpool Road
Dulles
VA
20166
USA

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is first by [getting the innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602241/6088109) of `addr` using `decode_contents()`, then split the resulting text using `.split(<br/>)`.

```
innerHtml = addr.decode_contents()
addr_list = innerHtml.split('<br/>')
print(addr_list)
```

Output:

```
['45120 Waxpool Road', '20166 Dulles, VA', 'USA']
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have to locate the `<br>` tags also with `find`, and split your text.

Please take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847891/beautifulsoup-fetching-text-either-side-of-a-br-tag). It may help you.

Hope it works.